# Online PCA with spectral bounds

Tags: r, pca

I have question regarding online PCA implemented in the [paper](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/el327/papers/opca2.pdf). I am interested in the Algorithm 2. I am not clear where the while loop stops. Also I have programmed it in R the problem is that the condotion in while loop is always true and while loop never stops. Can someone please explain step by step what does the Algorithm do?The algorithm is as follows:

> **input**: $X$,$\Delta$
>   $U\leftarrow$ all zero matrix (dimensions are not given in the paper , 0 rows and 0 columns)
>   $B\leftarrow$ a covariance sketch
>   **for** $x_t\in X$ **do**
>       Add $x_t$ to sketch $B$
>       **while** $||(I-U U^{\top})B||^2 \geq \Delta$
>           Add the top left singular vector of $(I-UU^{\top})B$ to $U$
>       **yield**$\;y_t=U^{\top}x_t$ (I think while loop ends before yielding, not mentioned in the paper)
>   **end for**

$x_t$ and $y_t$ are vectors.
Following is the R code I wrote:

```
PCA<-function(X,delta){
    n<-nrow(X)
    d<-ncol(X)
    B<-cov(X)
    Nrow<-nrow(B)
    Ncol<-ncol(B)
    U<-matrix(0,Nrow,Ncol)
    Y<-matrix(0,n,d)
    idx<-0
    for(i in 1:n){
      inc<-X[i,]
        B<-cbind(B,inc)
        Id<-diag(Nrow)
        while(norm((Id-(U%*%t(U)))%*%B,"2")^2 >= delta){
           idx=idx+1
            test<-(Id-(U%*%t(U)))%*%B
            topleft<-as.matrix(eigen(test%*%t(test))$vectors[,1])
            add<-cbind(U,topleft)
            U<-add[,which(!apply(add,2,FUN=function(x){all(x==0)}))]
        }
        y<-matrix(0,1,d)
        if(idx >0){y[1,1:idx]<-t(U)%*%X[i,]}
        Y[i,]<-y
    }
    Y<-Y[,which(!apply(add,2,FUN=function(x){all(x==0)}))]
    return(Y)
}
```

Then to test what I have done make sense I used Fisher iris data, and I got:

```
log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
ir.species <- iris[, 5]


ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir)
ir.pca$rotation #this is the built in r function equivalent output, which is very different then what I get in my understanding I get (ir.pca$x) from the online PCA implementation.


OPCA<-PCA(as.matrix(log.ir),300)#If you change the value 300 to 0.34 say then you will have X1,X2,X3 and X4
rotationOPCA<-data.frame(t(t(OPCA) %*% as.matrix(log.ir) %*% solve(cov(log.ir))))

                 X1         X2
Sepal.Length -46589.574 -21265.678
Sepal.Width    3521.197   1459.211
Petal.Length   2261.212   1058.487
Petal.Width    4220.653   1874.365
```

Now they(X1=PC1,X2=PC2) make absolutely no sense to me can anyone help with the interpretation?

Comment: Could you copy (the relevant parts of) algorithm 2 into the question to make it self-contained? This will make your question easier to find in a search engine, still readable if the link dies and will make sure that people answering your question don't have to open and search through a pdf.

Comment: @dimpol Thank you for the comment. I've done so, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: How would it matter whether the "yield" statement is part of the while loop or not?

Comment: I am unsure, perhaps affects the value of y_t due to the mapping done on U?

Comment: Shouldn't `idx<-0` be inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @Axeman I don't think so! It is an initialisation to the counter, `idx<-idx+1`,so at first iteration we have `idx<-1`, which is what I want, same concept as doing sum in the for loop.